# How to prove a number is not a prime number (without a computer)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Show that 
>   $$5994937829$$ is not prime number

How can I use math methods to prove it, and I know that this be proven using computer. But I can use only math methods to solve it.

Comment: If it is prime, Fermat's Little Theorem must hold, so perhaps you can use that to derive a contradiction. EDIT: See the answer by T. Bongers.

Comment: Thank you, How use Farmat's Little Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p = 5994937829$ were prime, then Fermat's little theorem implies that

$$a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$$

for all $a$. But this [does not hold](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E5994937829%20mod%205994937829), since

$$2^p \equiv 1030766071 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: why $2^p\equiv 1030766071$?

Comment: @chinamath This can be easily computed by successive squaring, for example - I linked to WA, and it should show up now.

Comment: No,I hope don't use any computer to prove this

Comment: @chinamath Using successive squaring, the residue $2^p$ can be computed by hand in a few minutes.

Comment: this maybe let $A=5994937829,
B=10^{180004}+ 248797842×10^{89998} + 1$,then we easy find $A=77377\times 77477$

Comment: @chinamath An easier method, which relies on the same lucky circumstance: if $A=pq$ is odd, then there are integers $t, u$ where $p=t-u, q=t+u, A=t^2-u^2$. Here, $\sqrt A\approx 77426.98$. So try $t=\lceil\sqrt A\rceil=77427$. Then $t^2-A=2500$ which is easily seen to be $u^2$ where $u=50$. But this worked only because $A$ is the product of two primes with small difference $2u$ where $u$ is easily recognised from $u^2$.